# Compulsary include during select with Random in MYSQL Query

Tags: mysql

I am selecting random id with my query like this

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(player_id) AS batsman
FROM
    (SELECT 
        player_id
    FROM
        tbl_match_players
    WHERE
        player_type = 2 AND player_match_id = 1
    ORDER BY player_id NOT IN (1) , RAND()
    LIMIT 3) t
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Currently its working fine as per my need but now I have added one column in table called `is_compulsory` when any row have value called 1, I want always return that id with my result as compulsory and it should not cross the limit.

For example, I have id called 2 and 3 have assigned  `is_compulsory = 1`, Now in my result I want compulsory include that two ids and then remain will be selected with random. So expected result should be like

```
example 1

2,3,5

example 2
2,3,4
```

My Table is like this

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_match_players` (
  `player_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `player_match_id` int NOT NULL,
  `player_team` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `player_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `player_type` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT '1 = wicket keeper 2 = batsman 3 = all rounder 4 = bowler',
  `is_compulsory` mediumint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `player_points` mediumint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

INSERT INTO `tbl_match_players` VALUES
( 1, 1, 'India'     , 'Player 1' , 1, 0, 0),
( 2, 1, 'India'     , 'Player 2' , 2, 1, 0),
( 3, 1, 'India'     , 'Player 3' , 2, 1, 0),
( 4, 1, 'Netherland', 'Player 4' , 2, 0, 0),
( 5, 1, 'India'     , 'Player 5' , 2, 0, 0),
( 6, 1, 'Netherland', 'Player 6' , 3, 0, 0),
( 7, 1, 'India'     , 'Player 7' , 3, 0, 0),
( 8, 1, 'India'     , 'Player 8' , 3, 0, 0),
( 9, 1, 'India'     , 'Player 9' , 4, 0, 0),
(10, 1, 'Netherland', 'Player 10', 4, 0, 0),
(11, 1, 'India'     , 'Player 11', 4, 0, 0);
```

This is [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FGf48Qw3) Link

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by modifying your query to ensure that the compulsory players are always included in the result.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(player_id) AS batsman
FROM (
    SELECT player_id
    FROM tbl_match_players
    WHERE player_type = 2 AND player_match_id = 1
    ORDER BY is_compulsory DESC, RAND()
    LIMIT 3
)
ORDER BY RAND();
```

Comment: Hi! Its working like charm. Thanks!

Comment: This answer does not address your actual question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, I have found issue with it, but your answer missing my GROUP_CONCAT thing and it have still LIMIT issue in it. Can You Please test it with DBFIDDLE I have given in my question? Thanks!